# Opensky Symfony2 Intetegration

Tags: symfony, ldap

Is there any Step by Step tutorial to configure ZF2 Client in Symfony2?

Since I want to integrate Opensky LDAP bundle in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [README file](https://github.com/opensky/LdapBundle/blob/master/README.md) from Github?

> If you don't already have the ZF2 codebase available in the vendor path of your Symfony2 application, you may be interested in using [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) to pull in the LDAP client by itself. Instructions for this process are documented in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony-devs/N-uIGhEWgs8/CrFmiLFYQbEJ) from the symfony-devs mailing list.